# websphere jms connection pool sharing

Tags: jms, websphere, connection-pooling

After reading several articles on jms connection pooling I got confused.

Could one please explain if queue connection factory configured in the cluster scope with maximum 10 connections (default) will allow 10 concurrent connections per cluster or per cluster member ?

So, in case of 4 cluster members there can be total of 10 or 40 connections opened ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max connections are per server instance (you'll have a total of 40 connections in your case). Actually all resource definitions work this way. The scope in which a resource is defined  only governs which server instances can reach this definition.

Quoting from [infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rcon_scope.html) ;

> Despite the scope of a defined resource, the resource properties apply
>   at an individual server level only. For example, if you define the
>   scope of a data source at the cell level, all the users in that cell
>   can look up and use that data source, which is unique within that
>   cell. However, resource property settings are local to each server in
>   the cell. For example, if you define the maximum connections as 10,
>   then each server in that cell can have 10 connections.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. That's the answer I was looking for.